# Linking word for "in exchange"?

Tags: adverbs, linking-verbs

I'm looking for a linking word that can connect two sentences:

> Omitting the predefined parameter relaxes the potential charging destinations at a step to be the entire sensors, thereby expanding the potential trajectory space. ______, it requires the charging algorithm to strike a balance between extending the network lifetime and the efficiency of the MC.

I mean, I am doing action A to gain an advantage B, "in exchange", I have to accept a disadvantage C (I don't want to deal with it, but, it is acceptable since we gain advantage B).

What linking words I can use instead of "in exchange" in this situation? Actually, I don't even know whether "in exchange" exists or not :(

Comment: "in exchange" _does_ exist, but you probably need "... despite it/this requiring..." Or maybe "although it/this requires". (I prefer "...despite this...") By the way, I don't understand "relaxes the potential charging destinations at a step to be the entire sensors". Also, perhaps it should be "network's lifetime" or "lifetime of the network".

Comment: What is the problem with using _however_? It's the right word in such contexts. (I agree with Old Brixtonian about the _...at a step to be..._, though.) You could also try _as a trade-off_.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian, thanks for your advice. A trajectory (solution) = sequence of actions. At each action step, there is a set of sensors requesting to be charged. Firstly, one sensor in this set is chosen to be charged in this action step.  with "relaxes the potential charging destinations at a step to be the entire sensors." If I omit the predefined parameter, I do not maintain the set of requesting sensors anymore; any sensors can be considered the next charging destination at each step. Could you help me clear this sentence? Sorry about my poor English.

Comment: @user405662, initially, I used "however". I don't know why I changed my mind. Anyway, you guys found another critical issue in this paragraph. I explained in my previous comment, could you help me out?

Comment: I didn't notice the full stop after "space". <b>However</b> is better at the start of the second sentence, as user405662 suggested. I'm afraid I don't understand the science, so I can't help. I don't like "at each _action step_". "*at each step*" might suffice.

Comment: What is "the entire sensors"? Can you just use *Still* or *At the same time*?

Comment: A common concessive ('I have to accept a disadvantage C (I don't _want_ to [have to] deal with it, but it is acceptable since we gain advantage B) is 'admittedly'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As nobody has thought of a word that encompasses the “consequently” of @Leachoid with the sense of reciprocal loss, I suspect that one needs to find another way of linking the two sentences. I think one can do better than “In exchange”, especially if one reconsiders the rather clumsy (IMHO) “requires” construction. In colloquial speech one could write:

> The **trade-off** for this is that the charging algorithm **must** strike a balance…

and more formally, something like

> **This comes at the cost of ensuring** that the charging algorithm strikes a balance…

or

> **This comes at the cost of altering** the charging algorithm **so that it** strikes a balance…

depending on the science.

But using the word *cost* ensures that the sense of reciprocal loss is understood.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the word "Consequently". It derives from "consequence" that implies some downside or compromise arising from the initial action.   https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consequently?q=Consequently